# Reduce ffmpeg process time

Tags: video, ffmpeg

First off, I'm not worried about video quality, I will be using the output file for very small thumbnails so the quality is not the top priority, speed is.

I have tried setting `-q:v 1`, `-crf 27`, `-preset ultrafast`. Everything I've tried still gives me the same process time 6.7seconds for a 13MB video.

Here is what I've tried:

```
-i VideoInput.mp4 -c:v libx264 -q:v 1 -crf 27 -s 100x100 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

As you can see I've tried scaling the video to a very small size in the attempt to reduce process time, I have also tried reducing the bitrate with `-b:v`.

Can someone please advice me on how to speed up the process time?

Comment: If you reduce the speed it will take longer.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Please see my edit, I would like to reduce the process time (the time it takes for the command to complete). Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Go for `-preset superfast`

Comment: Check how long the sole decoding takes: [null muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#null).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I tried `-ffmpeg -i VideoImput.mp4 -f null out.null` and the process time remains 6.7 seconds.

Comment: Seems to be your only option is to get a better pc.

Comment: @MátéJuhász hahaha I'm running it on android. I've tested in on my mac as well.

Comment: As for the encoding side refer to the log. Ensure that it does not contain a message from libx264: `using cpu capabilities: none!` which is often seen on Android from a popular, but apparently broken compiling script using `--disable-asm` for x264. `-q:v` is ignored by x264: use `-crf` instead.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard thank you for your reply,  I will look in the log for `using cpu capabilities: none!`. I'm using `-crf` as the log warned me not to use `-q:v`. I done another test and found that on my mac the process time is 1second and on android 8seconds with a 15MB input.

Comment: @Gyan OP has set ultrafast which seems to be faster as per the doc https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264